# two finder windows next to each other like Ubuntu F3 shortcut

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, finder

Ok, so at work I use Ubuntu and its create for copying a files from one folder to another folder without having two finder windows open.

What I would like is to have that function on my mac and I am wondering if anyone knows how to do this.

I understand Ubuntu is Linux and Mac well its from Linux has all the features of Linux but is a mac. The feature may not be there but if it is, it would help me alot.

As I am always moving files around servers and systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is one of the features of [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/):

[image]

⌘U toggles dual pane mode and ⌥⇥ focuses the other pane.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a split pane window mode, this is not available in the stock version of Finder shipped by Apple. However there are numerous Finder extensions such as the freeware [XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) that can accomplish this task.